# Mysql where in multiple rows

Tags: mysql, where-clause

I have this problem.

One table with.

```
id | routename | usersid   | 
1  | route 1   | 1,2,3,5 2 | 
2  | route 2   | 5,20,15 3 | 
4  | route 4   | 10,15,7,5 |
```

I need, search ej. userid 5 in colum usersid... but I have no idea how to do, because there are multiple rows.

Comment: It's unclear as to how the data is formatted.. I recommend pasting a snippet, clean it up if you need it to be secure.

Comment: is userid a foreign key or a varchar with the ids separated by comma?

Comment: This is a bad schema - you SHOULD change it to split usersid. Have separate table matching id with usersid.

Comment: userid is varchar with serparated by comma..
I can not change the design of the database :S

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot change the schema then you will have to use the `REGEXP` operator to match on a regular expression.  For example

```
where column REGEXP '(^|,)5(,|$)'
```

This matches the number `5` either at the beginning or end of the field or surrounded by commas (or any combination thereof), to avoid matching other numbers like `15`, `55` or `1234567890`.

If the table is large this will perform very slowly as it will require a full table scan

Comment: wow, it's great
It works perfect. 
The table will have approx 500 records.
Thank you very much.... I'm glad the night :)

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for **[FIND_IN_SET()](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-find_in_set-function.php)**.

```
select * from Table1
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(5,usersid)
```

**[SAMPLE FIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/889c1/1)**

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp . See warning section